# I get the wrong character, even using HTML encoding

Tags: html, utf-8, html-encode

On a website I use the futura font. I use some french language text, so I need the "à" character, amongst others. I use UTF-8 charset.
Weirdly, the "à" shows up as an r with an accent on top (see the pic)
i tried HTML encoding

```
&agrave;
```

But the result is the same. Is there something I can do about it?
[image: The character that is supposed to be "à"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rather insufficient information in the question, but the probable explanation is that the HTML document is not in the UTF-8 encoding but in the ISO-8859-1 and the browser is interpreting it as ISO-8859-2 encoded. The letter “à” has the code E0 (hexadecimal) in ISO-8859-1; in ISO-8859-2, this code denotes the letter “ŕ”.

How to fix this? It depends on how the problem was created, especially how the character encoding is declared (or guessed by browsers). See 
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations .